# Dictionary lookup vs Array lookup; Array llocation vs dictionary allocation

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dictionary

can any of you tell me what is the behind-the-scene of lookup method for dictionary structure 
. I mean how it is implemented? Given a key we find the value in a dictionary.

1)We know that and array lookup is O(1) operation. So what about a dictionary?

2)If I am storing key value pairs where both are integers, if there is a huge amount of such Data and space is my concern which will be preferable? An array or a dictionary? 
For example I can allocate an array with a fixed size. But the key value pairs may not occupy the whole array. Its size may be half of the array. But the array allocation should be of maximum size as I don't know the whether a certain key will appear or not.
let me clarify, let we have key,value pairs (10,1), (20,2), (30,3). So if I use array then i have to declare its size as [30][2] though it only occupies 3 entries. So, is dictionary will be a better in this case. Not that 30 can be of million. So other entries will occupy memory in the array right?

Comment: Definitely use a dictionary (or a List).

Comment: Yes I have decided to use dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are usually implemented in two ways, a hash map or a binary tree.

1:  If the dictionary is a binary tree, then the search time is a binary search and thus O(log n).

If the dictionary is a hash map, then the search time is O(1). (Might increase to O(m) for keys with the same hash)

2: You are right, a dictionary will be a better use of space in this case of a sparse set of data. The extra time costs for the dictionary search is going to be relatively low.

Searching with the dictionary can be further improved with something like a bloom filter(if the average case is the object not existing in the hash map).

Comment: Note that .Net Dictionary is implemented as hashmap - so O(1) lookups.

Comment: Oh thats great. I am using this in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The term `dictionary` is very generic and can refer to any kind of data structure. Also you did not say whether it is an ordered dictionary or unordered. There are all kinds of binary search trees balanced in various ways, n-ary trees, hash tables, skiplists, etc.

As far as arrays go, straight flat arrays do waste space when they are sparsely populated. However, you can implement multi-level arrays. The first few levels are directories, and only the leaf level has small arrays.

Virtual memory page tables are often implemented this way.

So what happens is that an array index like (hex) [0x123456] might get broken up with bitmasking operations into [0x12][0x34][0x56]. Select the top directory, which is an array of pointers to middle directories, which have arrays of pointers to little tables. (Of course, in reality, the code has to walk the levels and watch out for missing directories and tables rather than indexing directly! That's the whole point: not to have the whole tree instantiated.)

Not long ago I implemented Unicode character sets in a regular expression engine this way, using these kinds of structures of several different depths for different situations.

Of course this has nothing to do with your regular `new int[foo]` C++ arrays! But can of course be hidden behind a class that looks like an array.

Comment: my dictionary is not ordered.

Comment: "your" dictionary? What is it? If it's your dictionary, why don't you know how it works internally? *puzzled*